# Index browser (UI tool) for Lucene .NET index

Tags: .net, lucene.net, lucene

Index browser (UI tool) for Lucene .NET index - does it exist? I know about LUKE, which was (development stopped years ago) index browser tool for a Java's version of Lucene, but what about .NET?

Comment: Index files are binary compatible between .NET and java, so theres no real need to have a Luke.Net

Comment: Really? That should make my life a lot easier. But what about a backward compatibility? The newest version of Luke is dated back to 2009, will it work with a index data created by recent (non-beta) version of Lucene .NET (April-2012)?

Comment: perharps you checked the old website, it is now hosted at http://code.google.com/p/luke/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke was updated 2012/12/28 to 3.5.0, which contains Lucene 3.5.0.

Luke 3.5.0 browses a Lucene.NET 2.9.2 index perfectly well.